# Smart "Who wants to be a millionaire" percentage algorithm

Tags: random, distribution, percentage

I'm writing a "who wants to be a millionaire" clone and stumbled upon a little problem I can't get my head around.

I have a joker that shows a percentage for each answer, displaying the likelihood that the answer is correct. I do this by assigning 15 percent to each wrong answer and the remaining 55 percent to the right answer.

Then I use a loop that loops (level * 10) times across these answers and distributes one percent from one of the answers (chosen randomly) to one of the other answers (chosen randomly also).

The idea behind it is, that lower levels would still pretty much show the true answer peeking out with a higher percentage, but that higher levels would have a high chance of either showing a wrong answer with the most percentages or an overall equality between the answers.

Alas, it's not working quite as well as envisioned, even at high levels (goes up to 12) the true answer is still very very obviously visible and I have no real idea what kind of algorithm I could use to make this better?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could try using an exponential distortion instead of a linear one.

See an implementation in JavaScript here: [http://jsfiddle.net/hua7R/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/hua7R/)

First we set the number of levels and the exponential distortion:

```
var levels=12,
    distortion=5;
```

The following function isn't important, I only used it in order to have the logs distributed in columns.

```
function numToStr(n){
    var s=String(n);
    for(var i=s.length;i<3;i++){
        s=' '+s;
    }
    return s;
}
```

We iterate through all levels in order to see the differences between them:

```
for(var l=0;l<=levels;l++){

    //In this test the right solution is always the last:

    var percentages=[15,15,15,55];

    /*The following function gives us a random number from 0 (included)
      to `percentage`'s lenght (not included).
      If it's called with the argument `true`, it checks if we can
      subtract 1 to that percentage (we don't want negative percentages).*/

    function random(cond){
        var i=Math.floor(Math.random()*percentages.length);
        if(!cond||percentages[i]>0){
            return i;
        }
        return random(true);
    }

    /*Then we iterate from 0 to the maximum value between `l*10`
      (`l` is the current level) and `l` raised to the power of `distortion`*/

    for(var i=0;i<Math.max(l*10,Math.pow(l,distortion));i++){
        percentages[random(true)]--;
        percentages[random()]++;
    }

    //Finally, the log:

    document.getElementById('log').innerHTML+="level "+numToStr(l)+" -> ["+numToStr(percentages[0])+", "+numToStr(percentages[1])+", "+numToStr(percentages[2])+", "+numToStr(percentages[3])+"]\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without getting analytical about probability distributions, I think a simple to understand algorithm that might work for you goes like this:

```
select 100 rand numbers from 1 to n (I will get to how you set n)
calculate how many 1's,2's,3's and numbers >= 4 you get
Use these counts as your answer scores, with the counts for >=4 being for the correct answer
```

So, for instance if you get n to 4, you will get, on average, a 25% score for all answers. If you set n to 5, then the correct answer gets assigned, on average, 40% score.  By varying n, the number of rands you draw and how you map the numbers to the answers (for isntance, you can assign 1 and 2 to the second best answer etc), you can vary the mean and variance with great precision.

These are definitely better ways to do this directly if you understand more about probability distributions.  This method is only for its algorithmic simplicity.

Comment: This is one of those situations where I would like to accept both answers, because they are both clever, each in their own way. I hope it's okay that I select Oriols solution, because I basically can plug it in right as it is.